# Keep button pressed by default / while on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I couldn't find out whether this problem is solved before.
I've got four buttons on a web page. 
My Questions are given below

1. Can I make the first one look "pressed" by default, when the user lands on the page?
2. How do I keep them in the "pressed" state as long as user on this page? 3. They will get "unpressed" whenever user makes a click anywhere in this page else.
   I'm sure it can be done with jQuery, but I can't figure out how.

```css
ul.buttons {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 3px;
 font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
ul.buttons li button {
   background-color: white;
   border: none;
   color: black;
   padding-bottom:0; 
   margin-left: -10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   font-size: 16px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
 outline:none;
}
 
button:focus::before {content: '×  ';
```

```html
<ul class="buttons">
    <li id="allbutton"><button autofocus">All</button></li>
    <li id="artbutton"><button>Art</button></li>
 <li id="musicbutton"><button>Music</button></li>
 <li id="writingbutton"><button>Writing</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why not use a div with custom styling instead of the buttons?

Comment: @SomenathSinha while other elements could be used, if these are indeed buttons then `<button>` is fine here and is more semantic than a generic `<div>`. From a CSS styling standpoint there will be a little extra work but nothing huge. For this post, focus on the functionality requests.

Comment: @SomenathSinha these are real buttons, each acts like a filter for a list of projects. i think that would be difficult with <div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make them look like 3D first...
Then when they are clicked, `addClass` that plays with border widths and translation to give a visual impression that the button is pressed.

I've made a quick example here, which may not be perfect... But will be a good start for you:

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
 
 // Remove the class to all buttons
 $("button").each(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("pressed");
 });
 
 // Add the class to the clicked button
 $(this).addClass("pressed");
});

// First button is pressed by default
$("button").first().click();
```

```css
ul.buttons {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 3px;
 font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}
ul.buttons li button {
 background-color: white;
 border: none;
 color: black;
 /* padding-bottom:0; */
 margin-left: -10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 16px;
 cursor: pointer;

 /* added */
 transition: all 0.2s linear;
 outline: 0;
 border-top:0px;
 border-right:0px;
 border-bottom:4px solid #9F9D9D;
 border-left:2px solid black;
 margin:5px;
 padding-left:1em;
}

button:focus {
 outline:none;
}

/* Everything below is added */
 button::before {
 /*content: '- ';*/
}
button.pressed:before {
 content: '× ';
}
button.pressed{
 box-shadow: none;
 -ms-transform: translate3d(-1px, 2px, 0);
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1px, 2px, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-1px, 2px, 0);

 border-top:0px !important;
 border-right:0px !important;
 border-bottom:0px !important;
 border-left:0px !important;
 padding-left:0.3em !important;
}



/* added only to see the buttons */
body{
 background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="buttons">
 <li id="allbutton"><button autofocus>All</button></li>
 <li id="artbutton"><button>Art</button></li>
 <li id="musicbutton"><button>Music</button></li>
 <li id="writingbutton"><button>Writing</button></li>
</ul>
```

Notice that I added a `padding-left` to reserve the space used the "x" that is added in the button...

Comment: This seems to be just what I need, however it doesn't work when I implement it in my document (buttons don't respond to clicks at all). I'll try to find where the mistake is. Thank you!!!

Comment: I figured it out – had to add    `$(document).ready(function(){`
before the script,  now it's working! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using some javascript if you prefer?..
see demo below

```js
var all_specific_btn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
console.log(all_specific_btn);
for (var index = 0; index < all_specific_btn.length; ++index) {

  all_specific_btn[index].onclick = function() {
    for (var index = 0; index < all_specific_btn.length; ++index) {
      console.log(all_specific_btn[index].children);
      if (all_specific_btn[index].children[0].style.opacity != "0") {
        all_specific_btn[index].children[0].style.opacity = "0"
      }
    }
    this.children[0].style.opacity = "1";
  }
}
```

```css
ul.buttons {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
ul.buttons li button {
  background-color: white;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.x {
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn{
  display:table;
}
```

```html
<ul class="buttons">
  <li id="allbutton" class="btn">
     <span>x</span><button autofocus>All</button>
  </li>
    <li id="artbutton " class="btn ">
      <span>x</span>
       <button>Art</button>
    </li>
 <li id="musicbutton "  class="btn ">
      <span>x</span>
      <button>Music</button>
  </li>
 <li id="writingbutton "  class="btn ">
      <span>x</span>
      <button>Writing</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```